# krajee bootstrap file input upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

First , i am a french web developer ( sorry for my poor english )

i 'am looking for a bootstrap php **image upload with thumbnail**.

i would like to make an upload image file like :

[http://www.2ememain.be/inserer/][1]

the Krajee plugin ([http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input][2]) seems to be  the one i am looking for..

But i have some problems with the upload..

i get the error message:

**item1.png: SyntaxError: Unexpected token e**

*my form:*

```
   <input id="input-700" name="kartik-input-700" type="file" multiple=true class="file-loading">
```

*js:*

```
 $("#input-700").fileinput({
uploadUrl: "upload.php",
uploadAsync: true,
maxFileCount: 10});
```

*upload.php:*

```
echo "test";

if (empty($_FILES['input-700'])) {
echo json_encode(['error'=>'No files found for upload.']); 
return; 
}

// get the files posted
$images = $_FILES['input-700'];
var_dump($images);
```

More strange:
when i delete echo(test);
i get the error:
**No files found for upload**

Thanks for your support

if you have another solution , i shall be glad to get it..

Comment: hi kindly refer to this link mine works well with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626410/krajee-bootstrap-file-input-catching-ajax-success-response

Answer (score 2):

Since you have set the `uploadUrl` parameter you are using the ajax uploads feature (instead of native HTML form submission).

You need to ensure that you return a proper JSON encoded data response from the server action (as set in `uploadUrl`) else the plugin fails. You can read the [plugin documentation for ajax uploads](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-uploads) where this is highlighted. For example, even if you do not have any data to send - you can send a empty JSON string like `{}`.