# Krajee Bootstrap File Input, catching AJAX success response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Krajee the Bootstrap File Input plugin to perform an upload via AJAX call.

Here is the link to the Krajee plugin AJAX section: [Krajee plugin AJAX](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#ajax-uploads)

The JS and PHP (codeigniter) codes I'm using are as following:

JS:

```
<script>        
    $("#file-upload").fileinput({ 
        'allowedFileExtensions' : ['csv'],
        'maxFileSize': 5120,
        'maxFileCount': 1,
        'uploadUrl': 'dashboard/uploader',
        'elErrorContainer': '#errorBlock',
        'uploadAsync': true,
        'msgInvalidFileExtension': 'Invalid extension for file "{name}". Only "{extensions}" files are supported.',
        'uploadExtraData': {csrf_token_name: $("input[name=csrf_token_name]").val()}
    });       
</script>
```

PHP:

```
public function uploader(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './csv_uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '5120';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file-upload")){
        $data['error'] = 'The following error occured : '.$this->upload->display_errors().'Click on "Remove" and try again!';
        echo json_encode($data); 
    } else {
        echo json_encode("success"); 
    }            
}
```

Right now I get a response from PHP whatever it is an error or a success as JSON, I have went through the plugin documentation and I still can't find how to catch the AJAX response and act according to that response as we do in jQuery with the ajax success function :

```
success: function (response) {
            //Deal with the server side "response" data.
         },
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check out a demo here [live demo](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/11)

Remember to set **uploadAsync false** if you want the success event fire

Example code:

JS

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
    showRemove:false,
    showPreview: false,
    uploadUrl: "../xxxx/xxxx/XXXXXX.php", // server upload action
    uploadAsync: false,
    uploadExtraData: function() {
        return {
            bdInteli: xxxx
        };
    }
});

// CATCH RESPONSE
$('#input-id').on('filebatchuploaderror', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra, 
    response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
});

$('#input-id').on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra, 
    response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
    alert (extra.bdInteli + " " +  response.uploaded);
});
```

PHP

```
$nombre = $_FILES["ficheroExcel"]["name"];
$bdInteli = $_POST['bdInteli'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ficheroExcel"]["tmp_name"], $nombre) ){
    $output = array('uploaded' => 'OK' );
} else {
   $output = array('uploaded' => 'ERROR' );
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: @MuhammadYounas you need to set uploadAsync false. I've updated the code

Answer (score 8):

You can read the [events section on the plugin documentation page](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#events) to understand the various events provided by the plugin.

It depends on how you have setup the ajax upload in the plugin. The plugin offers two [ajax upload modes - synchronous and asynchronous](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-uploads) as described in the documentation. Its asynchronous if you have `uploadAsync` property set to `true`.

FOR AJAX SUCCESS TRAP:

- you can use the [filebatchuploadsuccess](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-filebatchuploadsuccess) event for synchronous
  uploads
- you can use [fileuploaded](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileuploaded) event for asynchronous uploads

FOR AJAX ERROR TRAP:

- you can use the [filebatchuploaderror](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-filebatchuploaderror) event for synchronous
  uploads
- you can use [fileuploaderror](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#event-fileuploaderror) event for asynchronous uploads

In your case you have set `uploadAsync` set to true - so use the asynchronous settings/events.

Comment: This is the right answer. The accepted one haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this sample code in your test.in my test,my response data      like this:

```
response data:
{
"ver":"1.0",
"ret":true,
"errmsg":null,
"errcode":0,
"data":{
    "status":"upload success",
    "originalFilename":"testFileName.txt",
    "fileName":"excelFile",
    "fileType":"text/plain",
    "fileSize":1733
}

 javascript code:
 $('#input-id').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    var response = data.response;
    if(response.ret ) {
        alert("upload success!"+data.response.data);
    }else{
        alert("upload failed!"+response.errmsg)
    }
    alert('File uploaded triggered'+form+"response:"+response);
    console.info(response.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30414801/1053191), i have done like this

**javascript** :

```
$('#input-id').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
        response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
    console.log('File uploaded successfully : ID '+ data.response.d);
});
```

In **ASHX** File add response to the context:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
string myId = "NewwId 1";
var wrapper = new { d = myId };
context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'icon_path')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options'           =>  ['accept' => 'image/*','multiple'=>false, 'id' => 'category_icon_image'],
        'pluginLoading'     =>  false,
        'pluginOptions'     =>  [
        'initialPreview'        =>  (!$model->isNewRecord) ? [
            'web/filebox/'.$model->icon_path
        ] : '',
            'initialPreviewAsData'  =>  true,
            'browseIcon'            =>  '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
            'showPreview'           =>  true,
            'showCaption'           =>  false,
            'showRemove'            =>  false,
            'showUpload'            =>  false,
            'showClose'             =>  false,
            'previewTemplates'      =>  'object',
            'layoutTemplates'       =>  'preview',
            'uploadUrl'             =>  'category-item/category-item/ajax-image-upload',
            'uploadAsync'           =>  false,
            'deleteUrl'             =>  Url::toRoute('category-item/delete-image?id='.$model->category_item_id)
        ],
        'pluginEvents'  =>  [
            'filebatchuploadsuccess' => 'function(event, data, previewId, index) {
                console.log(data.response)
            }',
            'filebatchselected' => "function(event,files){
                var input = $('#category_icon_image');
                input.fileinput('upload');
                $('#categoryitem-icon_path_pre').val(files[0].name);
            }",
        ],
    ])
?>
```